# CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js requiring authentication

Tags: authentication, server, coldfusion

Since this morning my website is requiring authentication for everyone who tries to access it. The website says:

```
https://--example-- is requesting your username and password. The site says: “Protected Folder”
```

After I click on cancel the authentication, the browser console shows:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://--example--/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js”.  index.cfm:3
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://--example--/CFIDE/scripts/masks.js”.
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Talk to your hosting company. Odds are, they restricted access to that folder `/CFIDE` since it is primarily for the CF Administrator tool. People often do that and forget that the `/scripts/` folder is there. Depending on how many `cfform`s you're using, it might be better to refactor them to use basic HTML and JavaScript/jQuery. If the hosting company doesn't want to budge, you may have to do that anyway.

Comment: What version of CF are you using? I think CF 2016 moved the `/scripts` folder out of the `/CFIDE` folder for just this kind of reason.